# How to drag and drop multiple element bottom of selected element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, position, draggable, drop

I want to develop playing card game and want to move the multiple cards between decks. So I just built simple drag and drap example.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="example-parent">
    <div class="example-origin" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);">
      <div id="draggable-1" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" 
      ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
        item1
      </div>
      <div id="draggable-2" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" 
       ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
        item2
      </div>
      <div id="draggable-3" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" 
       ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
         item3
      </div>
      <div id="draggable-4" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" 
       ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
         item4
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="example-dropzone" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);">
      dropzone
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body{
width: 40%;
}

.example-parent {
border: 2px solid #DFA612;
color: black;
display: flex;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

.example-origin {
flex-basis: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
padding: 10px;
}

.example-draggable {
background-color: #4AAE9B;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

.example-dropzone {
background-color: #6DB65B;
flex-basis: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
padding: 10px;
}
```

**script.js**

```
function onDragStart(event) {
event
  .dataTransfer
  .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop(event) {
const id = event
  .dataTransfer
  .getData('text');

const draggableElement = document.getElementById(id);  
const dropzone = event.target;
dropzone.appendChild(draggableElement);
event.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
```

```js
function onDragStart(event) {
    event
      .dataTransfer
      .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop(event) {
    const id = event
      .dataTransfer
      .getData('text');
    
    const draggableElement = document.getElementById(id);  
    const dropzone = event.target;
    dropzone.appendChild(draggableElement);
    event.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
```

```css
body{
    width: 40%;
}

.example-parent {
    border: 2px solid #DFA612;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .example-origin {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .example-draggable {
    background-color: #4AAE9B;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .example-dropzone {
    background-color: #6DB65B;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
  }

This is how it is working.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example-parent">
        <div class="example-origin" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);">
          <div id="draggable-1" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
            item1
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-2" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
            item2
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-3" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
             item3
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-4" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" >
             item4
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="example-dropzone" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event);">
          dropzone
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want to drag multiple elements. For example, when I drag item2, item3 and item4 must be draggable with item2 or when I drag item3, item4 must be draggable with it. And also when I drag items how to change their position with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code,I found it my question.

```js
  
var x="";
var y="";
var selected="";
var allelement="";

function onDragStart(event) {  
  x=event.pageX;
  y=event.pageY;
  event
      .dataTransfer
      .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
    
  allelement = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById(event.target.id).parentElement.children )

  var index = allelement.indexOf(event.target)
  selected= allelement.slice(index)
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image("0", "0"), -10, -10);
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
function drag(event){
  const movex=event.pageX - x;
  const movey=event.pageY - y;

  selected.forEach((item)=>{
  var element = document.getElementById(item.id);
  var css=
  "z-index:9999;pointer-events: none; transform: scale(1.05, 1.05) rotate(0deg) translate(" +
  movex +
  "px, " +
  movey +
  "px);";
  element.style.cssText = css;
})
}

function onDragEnter(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("dragenter ", event.target.id);
}

function onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop(event) {
 
    const id = event
      .dataTransfer
      .getData('text');

    const dropzone = event.target;
    selected.forEach((element)=>{

      var css = "z-index:0;pointer-events:auto;";
      element.style.cssText = css;
      dropzone.appendChild(element);
    })
    
}
```

```css
body{
    width: 80%;
}

.example-parent {
    border: 2px solid #DFA612;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .example-origin {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .example-draggable {
    background-color: #4AAE9B;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  
  .example-dropzone {
    background-color: #6DB65B;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left:100px ;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example-parent">
        <div class="example-origin" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" >
          <div id="draggable-1" class="example-draggable" draggable="true"  ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" ondrag="drag(event)" >
            item1
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-2" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" ondrag="drag(event)" >
            item2
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-3" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" ondrag="drag(event)" >
             item3
          </div>
          <div id="draggable-4" class="example-draggable" draggable="true" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragstart="onDragStart(event);" ondrag="drag(event)" >
             item4
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="example-dropzone" id="dropzone-0"  ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event)" >
          dropzone
        </div>
        <div class="example-dropzone" id="dropzone-1"  ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event)" >
          dropzone
        </div>
        <div class="example-dropzone" id="dropzone-2"  ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event)">
          dropzone
        </div>
        <div class="example-dropzone" id="dropzone-3"  ondragenter="onDragEnter(event)" ondragover="onDragOver(event);" ondrop="onDrop(event)">
          dropzone
        </div>
    </div>
<script >

</script>
</body>
</html>
```